# How to select Single ID in MYSQL

Tags: php

I have a table `citizens` with a field `id`, `title` and `link`. If I use these codes it will display all the content of id, what I need is when I click the first id id it should display the content of the row. I tried to remove the loop and change the array to assoc but when I select the second id it will always display the 1 id.

```
mysql_select_db("do",$con1);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM citizens ORDER BY id DESC"; 
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con1);
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){      
    echo $record['div'];
```

Comment: .. what? Do you mean where? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1` ?

Comment: i have 10 data in the field id 1-10 with their corresponding title and link or div, when i click the title 2 it always appear the content of id 1

Comment: .... What title? What link?

Comment: Do you mean `LIMIT` ? E.g. `SELECT * FROM citizens ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1` selects only one entry in the database.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get single record from database with id=1, try following:

```
$myID = 1; 

mysql_select_db("do",$con1);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM citizens WHERE id = $myID ORDER BY id DESC"; 
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $con1);

$record = mysql_fetch_row($myData);
echo $record['div'];
```

Comment: it says Undefined index: "echo $record['div'];

Comment: Maybe your table does't have this field? "div" it's name of column what from yout table. Put existing column name

Comment: it exist sir the code is running but my problem is that all the data from 1-10   will display how to remove the loop is my problem.

Comment: change echo $recors['div'] to var_dump($record) and write here the result

Comment: always display the content of row 1, even i select the row 2 still it display the first row

Comment: Do you change $myID = 1; to $myID = 2; ?